# Sobolev Bound for solution to Dirichlet Problem from knowledge of boundary estimates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

Take some bounded domain, $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 3$. Denote by $\partial \Omega$ the boundary of $\Omega$, which we take to be Lipschitz. Let $L$ be an elliptic operator that satisfies ellipticity and boundness conditions. Let $u$ be the solution to the following Dirichlet problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
Lu = 0 \qquad & \mbox{in} \quad \Omega \\
u = -v &\mbox{on} \quad \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Assume that we know the following is true about $v$
\begin{equation}
\sup_{\partial \Omega} (|v| + |\nabla v|) \leq C_1
\end{equation}
where $C_1$ is some positive constant. I am wondering, as a consequence of the inequality above, can we say
\begin{equation}
|| u ||_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \leq C_2
\end{equation}
where $C_2$ is a positive constant, possibly distinct from $C_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be subtleties depending on the exact assumptions that you make, but the general reasoning is as follows.

When $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, its trace on $\partial \Omega$ belongs to $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$. Conversely, if you take a $v \in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, you can find a $\bar{v} \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $\bar v = v$ on $\partial \Omega$ and
$$
\| \bar{v} \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C \| v \|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}.
$$
Then you look for $u$ under the form $u = u' + \bar{v}$ so that $u'$ is a solution to $Lu' = f$ with $f = - L\bar{v}$ and $u' = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. For this problem, you might know that
$$
\| u' \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C \| f \|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}
$$
and here you have
$$
\|f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \leq C \| \bar{v} \|_{H^1(\Omega)}.
$$
Putting all of this together leads you to the estimate
$$
\| u \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C \| v \|_{H^{1/2}(\Omega)}.
$$
Now the $H^{1/2}=W^{1/2,2}$ fractional Sobolev norm is bounded above by the $W^{1,\infty}$ norm which you use in your assumption.
So, *essentially*, what you are looking for is indeed valid.

As mentioned above, there are subtleties depending on the exact regularity of $\partial\Omega$ and on the coefficients of $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There two small questions I have. 1. Do you have a reference for the first inequality relating the H^1 norm and the H^{1/2} norm?  2. I am not sure where the two inequalities under "For this problem, you might know that" come from? Is there a reference for this? @cs89

Comment: For trace lifting result, you can see e.g. the second part of Theorem 18.40 of Leoni's book [A first course in Sobolev spaces](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-181/). For the resolution of $L u' =f$ with $f \in H^{-1}$ you can look e.g. Theorem 4.22 of Hunter's [lecture notes on PDEs](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf). Note that, once you know $u'$ exists, the bound $\|u'\|_{H^1} \leq \|f\|_{H^{-1}}$ is a straightforward energy estimate (just multiply the PDE by $u$ and integrate).

Comment: Thanks for the links to the references. Sorry for all the questions but I am looking at Theorem 18.40 of Leoni's book. It states that $||u||_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C ||g||_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}$. Am I correct in saying that $||g||_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}$ is the $H^{1/2}$-norm? I haven't seen the $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$- norm defined as the $L^2(\partial \Omega)$-norm before. I know that $g \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$ but I thought the $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$-norm was defined using the $H^1(\Omega)$-norm.

Comment: No. The $H^{1/2}$ norm is neither the $L^2$ nor the $H^1$ one, it is "in between". It is a "*fractional Sobolev space*". You can find many resources online or in textbooks or on this forum about them. Theorem 18.40 has two estimates, one that says $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|g\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}$ and one that says $\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \|g\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}+\|g\|_{B^{1-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega)}$, which is $H^{1/2}$ for $p = 2$. So heuristically, you can estimate a weak norm of $u$ by a weak norm of $g$ and a strong norm of $u$ by a strong one of $g$.

Comment: OK thanks for that! For the second inequality though I don't see the $H^1$norm of $u$, I see $|| \nabla u ||_{L^p}$? Is the $H^1$-norm bounded above by the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: The $H^1$ norm is precisely defined as the sum of the $L^2$ norm of $u$ and the $L^2$ norm of $\nabla u$.